# Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class TextView

Tags: android, textview, layout-inflater, inflate

**this first question in site.**

test all solution this site but not work!

i use textview in my layout application after run get error:

> 09-13 05:03:19.674 12726-12726/com.example.learning E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.learning, PID: 12726
>       android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class TextView
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
>           at com.example.learning.Adapters.ClothsAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(ClothsAdapter.java:28)
>           at com.example.learning.Adapters.ClothsAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(ClothsAdapter.java:16)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6493)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5680)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5563)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5559)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.LayoutState.next(LayoutState.java:100)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.fill(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.java:1570)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.java:682)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.java:604)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3693)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3410)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3962)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
>           at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1767)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
>           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1076)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:443)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2072)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1829)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
>           at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
>           at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
>           at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
>           at a

**xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_cloth"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:src="@drawable/clothes1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/margin_X2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/image_cloth"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name_cloth"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:text="test text"
            android:textSize="@dimen/largX2_font"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/standard_margin"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/view_count_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:text="700"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/name_cloth"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="@dimen/larg_font"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_view_count"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/view_count_text"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/view_count_text"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/view_count_text"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

## java file

```
public ClothsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_cloths, parent, false);
        return new ClothsViewHolder(view);
    }
```

**minSdkVersion:** 19

**targetSdkVersion:** 26

Comment: Can you show the values of `@dimen/largX2_font` & `@dimen/standard_margin`

Comment: @rahul-khurana   <dimen name="standard_margin">8dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_X2">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="form_fileds_margin">40dp</dimen>

Comment: what is `largX2_font` that you've mentioned in TextView?

Comment: a value bigger than standard_margin

Comment: `textSize` should be in `sp` not in `dp`

Comment: thanks , solved : i not set sp for value largx2_font

Comment: I have updated my answer accordingly. please accept and upvote if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try to change attribute textColor from `android:textColor="#000"` to `android:textColor="@color/yourColor"`

Comment: Hi, i am getting the same error, I already have the textColor in the same format as above